# python date string object to datetime object

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I get following response from an API:

```
/Date(1503964800000+0000)/
```

It is a string object. How do I convert it in to something like

```
2017-08-11T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp][1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) in combination with [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
import datetime

print(
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1502440590")).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
)
```

The result:

```
2017-08-11T10:36:30
```